# Deleting String template until '\n' In a large String - Java

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, string, substring

I'm having problem with `String`'s in `Java`. I have a large `String` with a lot of `\n` and  `\\n`. I want to delete entire rows that start with a certain template "Chorus:" and the rest of the row until `\n`.

I try to go over the `String` and searching the template "Chorus:". When i reach that, I concatenate the rest of the line until i reach to `\n`. Then i use `myString.reaplaceAll(subString," ")` and i get the same `String` as i started with.

**My Code:**

```
String string = " Police voice:\n"
                        + "Attention all units attention all units\n"
                        + "We have an All Points Bulletin out on a man with green hair\n"
                        + "I repeat we have an APB on a man with green hair\n" 
                        + "He's armed with a knife I repeat he's armed with a knife\n" 
                        + "Proceed with caution watch your back fella's\n"
                        + "He could be coming at your girlfriend next\n\n"

                        + "Verse 1:\n"
                        + "There's a joker on the loose from the psychiatric ward\n" 
                        + "His face is up on the bulletin board with a reward\n"
                        + "He'll stab you with a sword don't be fooled by his charm\n" 
                        + "He's probably armed with intent to do bodily harm\n"
                        + "Ring the alarm, look for a man with green hair\n"
                        + "Check at your girl's house, he was last seen there\n" 
                        + "He's has a mean stare but usually crack's jokes\n"
                        + "Good luck on your mission and guard your backs folks\n\n"

                        + "Chorus:\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!\n\n" 

                        + "Verse 2:\n"
                        + "We got the walkie-talkies to keep us all informed\n"
                        + "Suited up head to toe in detective uniforms\n"
                        + "Our unit storms in, we split the ghetto in sectors\n"
                        + "Locking down every block and put up metal detectors\n"
                        + "Protectors and be sure that you stand close\n"
                        + "Watch each others backs and guard your command post\n"
                        + "And most of all be advised that he's wise\n"
                        + "He could be disguised as one of your very own guys\n\n"

                        + "Chorus:\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n" 
                        + "Why I oughtta\n" 
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!\n"

                        + "Verse 3:\n"
                        + "I'm on a solo mission to find him personally\n"
                        + "To settle the score and beat then him mercifully\n" 
                        + "For what he first did to me\n"
                        + "It's sure to be the last\n"
                        + "Following footprints with a magnifying glass\n" 
                        + "To drag his lying ass back to his padded cell\n"
                        + "I'm mad as hell, on the trail of the tattle tail\n" 
                        + "I heard a yell the voice sounded familiar\n"
                        + "Give me your girlfriend or I'm gonna kill ya\n\n" 

                        + "Chorus:\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n" 
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!\n\n"

                        + "Verse 4:\n"
                        + "I followed the voice that led down a flight of steps\n"
                        + "Sneezing at dust, and swinging at the spider-webs\n"
                        + "Inside the depths of his basement\n"
                        + "I taste lint in my mouth, then the lights in the place… went!\n"
                        + "I saw my life flash in front of my eyes\n"
                        + "I felt a butcher knife slash at one of my thighs\n"
                        + "None of my guys knew where I'm at I was doomed\n"
                        + "Then I remembered the flashlight in my costume\n\n"

                        + "Chorus: Eminem\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!\n\n"

                        + "Verse 5:\n"
                        + "Dealing with backstabber's there was one thing I learned\n"
                        + "They're only powerful when you got your back turned\n"
                        + "I yearned for the day that we finally met againf\n"
                        + "So I can give him a taste of his own medicine\n"
                        + "He shed his skin, then he promised to come clean\n"
                        + "I took his butcher knife and jabbed it into his spleen\n"
                        + "Cut him at the seam then dragged the fella home\n"
                        + "Beating him over the head with the telephone\n\n"

                        + "Police voice:\n"
                        + "Attention all cars, attention all cars\n"
                        + "Unit 313 has apprehended the suspect\n"
                        + "He's going back to the crazy home, I repeat\n"
                        + "He's going back to the crazy home, how about that?\n\n"

                        + "Chorus:\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!\n"
                        + "I make you think you're a best friend then\n" 
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Hit a bitch snake from the back, I make you think you're a best friend then\n"
                        + "Why I oughtta\n"
                        + "Stay away from him he ain't no good!";

        String subString = ""; // Searching for Chorus: (7 characters) sub sub string in string

        for (int i = 0;i < string.length();i++)
        {
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'C')
            {
                subString = string.substring(i,i + 7);
                subString += " "; // "Chorus: "
                //System.out.println(subString);
                if (subString.equals("Chorus:")) // Delete the row
                {
                    i += 7;
                    while (string.charAt(++i)!= '\n')
                    {
                        //System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
                        subString += string.charAt(i);
                    }
                    string = new String(string.replaceAll(subString, ""));
                }
            }
        }

        printString(string);


    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string to be printed on the console.
     */
    public static void printString(String string)
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help will be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**
For clarification:
converting `"abcChorus:def\n"+"gh\n"+"Chorus;ijk\n"+"lmnop"` to `"gh\n"+"lmnop"`

Comment: Did you try with `string.replace(subString,"");`  ?

Comment: @Idos I will now but where is the logic in it? Tried it. Same output. No change to the `String`.

Comment: After your edit I will have to re-look the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My complicated solution. 
I searched for "Chorus: " `String` in the `String` and concatenated the rest of the line (until `\n`) and replace those sub strings in the whole `String`. Then replacing all the "Chorus:" sub strings from the whole `String`.
Like that i tackle both `"Chorus:"` lines and `"Chorus: blablablalba"` lines.

Solution:

```
String subString = ""; // Searching for "Chorus: " (7 characters) sub string in string


for (int i = 0;i < string.length();i++)
{
    if (string.charAt(i) == 'C')
    {
        subString = string.substring(i,i + 8);
        //subString += " "; // "Chorus:"
        //System.out.println(subString);
        if (subString.equals("Chorus: ")) // Delete the row
        {
            i += 8;
            while (string.charAt(i)!= '\n')
            {
                //System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
                subString += string.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(subString);

            string = new String(string.replaceAll(subString, ""));
        }
    }
}

string = new String(string.replaceAll("Chorus:", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get into the base libraries of a language and see what they can do, instead of pushing chars yourself...

```
    String[] lines = string.split("\n"); // split into array at newlines
    String result = Stream.of(lines)
        .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("Chorus:"))   // filter however you like
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));      // re-join as string with newlines
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Confused :0. I  will go through it. But with my way, can you detect what's wrong? Or just try your posted method?

Comment: Actually, I have not put your method through debugging, but at least - following you comments - you create a subString variable with the content "Chorus: " (space at the end!) and compare it to "Chorus:" (without a space). This will never match.

Nevertheless, a general advice: we are in a mature language with appropriate libraries. If you find yourself writing nested loops, you probably overcomplicate things.

Comment: Also it saying `Lambda expression's parameter s cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.`

Comment: For the lambda error: you seem to already have a variable "s", which was not mentioned in your original question. In that case, rename the "s" in the lambda to something else which does not cause any name collisions.

Comment: `e` would do the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String new = old.trim()
```

It removes the leading and trailing spaces from string.

You can store the trimmed string somewhere.After that once you make the modification concatenate it as the way you want it.

Comment: Didn't helped me much.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim() This is the documentation of this command.Hope this helps. I never used it myself but do not think it's much challenging.

Comment: If it still does not work please add a comment I will try to run it myself.Can not do it right now,sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you denis. I'm currently trying @mtj method. Thank you for the response. If i get any problems i will post here again.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a use of regex and recursion too. Just call the removeStuff method on your String. 
You can also change and tweak the regex inside the compile method argument.

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Chorus([^\n]*)");
static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

public static String removeStuff(String myString, Matcher matcher) {
    if (matcher.find() == false) {
        return myString;
    }
    return removeStuff(string.replace(matcher.group(), ""), matcher);
}
```